# Crop a triangle from an image, using its center in android

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, crop

How can I crop a triangle from an image (given the degree) using it's center.

for e.g. In the below image, fig_1 is the original image. I want to cut it like fig_2, fig_3 and fig_4 where, x, y and z are the degree of the angles.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but you might want to use the `BitMap` class. First write the contents of the image to a `Buffer`, then use `copyPixelsFromBuffer(Buffer)` in `BitMap` class to get a `BitMap`. Then write the logic to edit the `BitMap`, e.g. you can use `eraseColor(int)`. Then copy your edited `BitMap` to an `ImageView` using `setImageBitMap(BitMap)` method in `ImageView` class.